# time measurement between 2 entries in database

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query to measure the time between two events. Let's assume I have the following entries in a database

| userid | event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | endpoint_called | 2022-04-29 22:07:22.342000 UTC |
| user1 | endpoint_200 | 2022-04-29 22:07:24.342000 UTC |
| user2 | endpoint_called | 2022-04-29 22:07:22.342000 UTC |
| user2 | endpoint_400 | 2022-04-29 22:07:27.342000 UTC |
| user3 | endpoint_called | 2022-04-29 22:07:22.342000 UTC |

**cases:**

- user1 has an entry for endpoint_called and endpoint_200
- user2 has an entry for endpoint_called and endpoint_400
- user3 has only endpoint called

**Now i need a query where:**

- if only endpoint is called for a user i have a timeout (count())
- if we have an endpoint_called and endpoint_200 for a user i need the time difference between these two timestamps
- if we have an endpoint_called and endpoint_400 i need the time difference between these two timestamps

user1, user2 or user3 are only dummies. I have a few Gigabyte of date with userNNNN

Any Idea how to solve this maybe in one query ?

Comment: mysql or bigquery? also show expected output

Comment: `LEAD()` is your friend here, but we need to know what kind of database you have, and we need to know more about your data (will users have more of these? If so, how do you decide where to set boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would get you what you want, and should work on any platform.

```
SELECT UserID,
        CASE 
          WHEN endpoint_200 IS NOT NULL THEN endpoint_called-endpoint_200
          WHEN endpoint_400 IS NOT NULL THEN endpoint_called-endpoint_400
          ELSE whatever_your_timeout_count_is_supposed_to_be
        END as ResultField
  FROM (
        SELECT UserID,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'endpoint_called' THEN timestamp 
                        ELSE NULL END) as endpoint_called,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'endpoint_200' THEN timestamp 
                        ELSE NULL END) as endpoint_200,
               MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'endpoint_400' THEN timestamp 
                        ELSE NULL END) as endpoint_400
          FROM YourTable
         GROUP BY UserID
       ) sub
```